# ggplot, geom_density_ridges2 and row height

Tags: r, ggplot2

With `ggplot2` and `geom_density_ridges2`, I try to plot two graphs. One with 2 rows and one with 9 rows.

On the two graphs I would like to keep the same height for each row. So the second graph should have the same width but it should be more than 4 times taller.

Unfortunately, Rstudio or `ggsave` give my graphs withs the same scale (same width, same height).

Code

```r
data_df = data.frame(text = character(), position = numeric())

# Plot
theme_set(theme_bw())
g = data_df %>%
    ggplot( aes(y=text, x=position, fill=text) ) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, max_position)) +
    geom_density_ridges2(alpha=1, stat="binline", scale=0.95, bins=200, show.legend = FALSE) +
    theme_ridges(font_size = 8, grid = TRUE, font_family = "",line_size = 0.5) +
    labs(x = "positions", y = author)

    
# Save image
image = paste0(author, ".png")
unlink(image)
ggsave(
    image,
    plot = g,
    device = "png",
    path = "graphs/",
    units = "mm",
    width = 100,
    scale = 1,
    dpi = 320,
    limitsize = FALSE
)
```

Is it possible to fix the height of the rows ?

Comment: Any code? Reprex would help.

Comment: Take a look at the `set_panel_size` function from the egg package :https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html. Is this what you are after?

Comment: How about a simple chunk of data using `dput()`?

Comment: @Mojoesque unfortunately, nope. I need same width but different heights. The height depends of the number of rows. I would like to have all the rows width the same height for all graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this or another approach with [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/index.html) could solve the problem?

```
library(patchwork)
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y =cyl)) +
    geom_point()


p1 + (p1 / plot_spacer() / plot_spacer() / plot_spacer())
```

[image]